# Python - Installing Scitools (std seems missing)

Tags: python

I've installed the SciTools package for Python 2.7 from sourceforge (mac osx 10.7). When I import it like this, it gives no error.

```
import scitools
```

But when I try to import like this (like it was shown in class):

```
from scitools.std import *
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from scitools.std import *
ImportError: No module named std
```

Anyone have an idea what could have been gone wrong?

Comment: Do you have a local file named `scitools.py`? What does `import scitools; print scitools.__file__` tell you?

Comment: It gives me this: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scitools/__init__.pyc

When searching for 'scitools.py' with the search function, I get no result.

Comment: That sounds correct; that's a common problem discounted then. :-)

Comment: Should there be a scitools.py file on my hard drive?

Comment: No, there should not. You state you got scitools from SourceForge, but I cannot find any such project there. Did you see the [installation instructions](https://code.google.com/p/scitools/wiki/Installation) listed on the Google Code page I did find?

Comment: My mistake, it was numpy and matplotlib that I got from SourceForge. The scitools package was installed a while ago, can't honestly remember where I got it. Think it was through terminal like this: 'curl -O http://scitools.googlecode.com/files/SciTools-0.3.tar.gz
      tar -xzf SciTools-0.3.tar.gz
      cd SciTools-0.3 
    
      sudo python setup.py install
      cd -
      sudo rm -r SciTools-0.3 SciTools-0.3.tar.gz'

Answer (score 2):

Your `scitools` version is *too old*. The `scitools.std` module was not introduced until version 0.6.

You have version 0.3 instead, where it is still called `scitools.all`. From the [ChangeLog](https://code.google.com/p/scitools/source/browse/ChangeLog):

> Version 0.6:
>
> [...]
>
> - The `all` module is renamed to `std`, i.e.,
>
>   ```
>   from scitools.all import *
>   ```
>
>   should now read
>
>   ```
>   from scitools.std import *
>   ```
>
>   The old name "`all`" is still available as a synonym for `std`, implying
>     that old programs will work. (The "`all`" name is misleading as only
>     a small portion of `scitools` is actually imported.)

You may want to upgrade your `scitools` installation to 0.9, the most recent release.